# Read file with UTF-8 in Haskell as IO String

Tags: haskell, utf-8

I have the following code which works fine unless the file has `utf-8` characteres :

```
module Main where
import Ref
main = do
    text <- getLine
    theInput <- readFile text
    writeFile ("a"++text) (unlist . proc . lines $ theInput)
```

With utf-8 characteres I get this:
`hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)`

Since the file I'm working with has `UTF-8` characters, I would like to handle this exception in order to reuse the functions imported from `Ref` if possible.

Is there a way to read a `UTF-8` file as `IO String` so I can reuse my `Ref`'s functions?. What modifications should I make to my code?. Thanks in Advance.

I attach the functions declarations from my `Ref` module:

```
unlist :: [String] -> String
proc :: [String] -> [String]
```

from prelude:

```
lines :: String -> [String]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I found the solution by myself.
Actually the file I was working with has this codification:

```
ISO-8859 text, with CR line terminators
```

So to work with that file with my haskell code It should have this codification instead:

```
UTF-8 Unicode text, with CR line terminators
```

You can check the file codification with the utility `file` like this:

```
$ file filename
```

To change the file codification follow the instructions from this [link](http://ask.xmodulo.com/change-character-encoding-text-file-linux.html)!

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with just GHC's basic (but extended from the standard) `System.IO` module, although you'll then have to use more functions:

```
module Main where

import Ref
import System.IO

main = do
    text <- getLine
    inputHandle <- openFile text ReadMode 
    hSetEncoding inputHandle utf8
    theInput <- hGetContents inputHandle
    outputHandle <- openFile ("a"++text) WriteMode
    hSetEncoding outputHandle utf8
    hPutStr outputHandle (unlist . proc . lines $ theInput)
    hClose outputHandle -- I guess this one is optional in this case.
```

Comment: The `hClose` is necessary to force GHC to flush the output buffer, by the way (doesn't automatically happen on program exit)

Answer (score 3):

Use [System.IO.Encoding](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/encoding-0.8/docs/System-IO-Encoding.html).

The lack of unicode support is a well known problem with with the standard Haskell IO library.

```
module Main where

import Prelude hiding (readFile, getLine, writeFile)
import System.IO.Encoding
import Data.Encoding.UTF8

main = do
    let ?enc = UTF8
    text <- getLine
    theInput <- readFile text
    writeFile ("a" ++ text) (unlist . proc . lines $ theInput)
```