# cabal install fails with "arithmetic overflow"

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

I saw a possible solution for an utf8 problem here: [Read file with UTF-8 in Haskell as IO String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444796/). I wanted to try that out, but I'm having a problem I can't resolve.

When I run the command `cabal v2-install encoding --lib` almost everything works but fails in the end with these lines:

> [8 of 8] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/cabal-install.-169090/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-169090/encoding-0.8.5/dist/setup/setup.hs, /tmp/cabal-install.-169090/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-169090/encoding-0.8.5/dist/setup/Main.o )
> Linking /tmp/cabal-install.-169090/dist-newstyle/tmp/src-169090/encoding-0.8.5/dist/setup/setup ...
> Configuring encoding-0.8.5...
> Preprocessing library for encoding-0.8.5..
> arithmetic overflow
> cabal: Failed to build encoding-0.8.5. See the build log above for details.

If I add `--verbose=3` to the command line the last few output lines are

> creating dist/build/Data
> creating dist/build/Data/Encoding
> Data/Encoding/ISO88592.hs generated from mapping
> Data/Encoding/ISO88592.mapping
> arithmetic overflow
> CallStack (from HasCallStack):
>     die', called at ./Distribution/Client/ProjectOrchestration.hs:1041:55 in 
> main:Distribution.Client.ProjectOrchestration
> cabal: Failed to build
> encoding-0.8.5-aa69e7dd952ebb6bcbe7b0947ad7f87838ecbfac327d0aa020c7f7f0f19b3e18.

I'm using cabal 3.2 and GHC 8.10.2 under Linux Mint 20.

I've looked "all over the place" for a solution, and the only trace of something similar is that the error is confirmed in [Gentoo's Bugzilla](https://bugs.gentoo.org/736276).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in the library *encoding* (I could reproduce it), and there's a fix available as a PR on the source repository:

https://github.com/dmwit/encoding/pull/11